# Sharing phone contact in Share Contract target terminates app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

Whenever I try to share a phonebook contact with a target app using Share Contract in WP 8.1, the target application always terminates before the `ReportCompleted()` method is called.

The contact is extracted using the `GetStorageItemsAsync()` as it's actually a `.VCF` file, but before I can direct the user through the target app's flow, the app terminates! The functionality is fine in case any other storage item (say an image) is shared.

Whatsapp(2.12.60 on WP 8.1) also shows the same behavior of terminating abrupty when a contact is shared.

Is this a bug in the OS? If not, how can I make this work?